# Showing 'Cannot POST/upload' in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I have made an endpoint for uploading a file. Weirdly enough the endpoint is working because the file is getting uploaded to my destination folder. I'm getting a 404 error in Postman. I have used multer for uploading file. [Snippet of postman of getting 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YkUM.png)

**upload.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads/");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 100
  }
});

router.post("/", upload.single("excel"), (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Uploaded successfully"
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**script.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const upload = require("./upload");
const cors = require("cors");
var xlsx = require("xlsx");

const app = express();
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());


//ENDPOINT FOR IMPORTING FILE
app.use("/upload", upload);



app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Server is up and running on port", 8080);
});
```

Comment: It is possible that your routes are not working properly.

try this
router.post("/upload", upload.single("excel"), (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Uploaded successfully"
  });
});

//ENDPOINT FOR IMPORTING FILE
app.use(upload);